# Is there a list of Korean words that were imported into Japanese?

Tags: word-origin

Many Korean words were incorporated from Japanese words. However, I wonder if the opposite is true.

How many Korean words were incorporated into Japanese? Is there any such research, maybe including a list of Korean words imported into Japanese?

Comment: I think with the 韓流 (jp: *hanryuu* kr: 한류) these sorts of borrowing are becoming much more common, and are often written in *katakana* (the writing system used for writing "foreign", non-Chinese words among other things). 

A recent-ish interesting phenomena I've encountered is people using 〜ニダ (from (습)니다) to make fun of Koreans and Korean speech. (Warning! Considered offensive to many...)

More benign examples include キムチ and ハニーバター :p

Comment: Until 19th century Korea was a bridge which connects Chinese and Japanese culture. Many of Sino-Korean and Sino-Japanese vocabularies share similar pronunciation. 난민 is なんみん[nanmin], 만족 is まんぞく[manzoku], 기력 is きりょく[kiryoku]. 
Before Meiji restoration, culture and knowledge were imported from Korea(and actually most of them are imported from China at first) to Japan and from colonial era of Korea, Japan started to export their own culture and linguistic characteristics to Korea.

Comment: During Korea's Three Kingdoms period, Japan did import many cultural elements from Korea (including Buddhism and probably the Chinese characters), but I think the flow of culture dwindled to an insignificant level by the latter half of the Joseon era, if not earlier.  By that time Japan started to trade with European countries, while Korea itself remained "the hermit kingdom".

Comment: @jungyh0218 That is a kind of answers that I'm looking for. Do you know any compiled sources?

Comment: @Blaszard I don't have my own source, but would it help you a little bit? http://blog.daum.net/_blog/BlogTypeView.do?blogid=0ZhF1&articleno=852&categoryId=10

Comment: How about 김치? In Japan, 김치(kimchi) is called as キムチ(kimuchi).

Comment: May be useful? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/332/are-there-any-old-loanwords-from-korean-especially-any-not-written-in-katakana

Answer (score 3):

Found good source. I am just reorganizing with some comments.
Original link : https://tip.daum.net/question/50543177 written in 2007

1. キムチ：김치
   Kimchi

2.　ビビンバ(ピビンバ라고도 씀）: 비빔밥
Bibimbob  - food

3. ソジュ：소주
   Soju - drink

4.　チョンガー：총각
Man who havent married yet

5.　チゲ : 찌개
Soup

6.　プルコギ : 불고기
Bulgogi

7.　コチュジャン : 고추장
[Go-choo-jang] It's spicy sauce

8.　ユッケ : 육회
raw beef dish. It's like sashimi instead of fish

9.　カルビ : 갈비
Galbi

12.　クッパ >국밥
This is name of food. Soup + rice

13.　ナムル > 나물
Vegetable Bean sprouts

14.　サンチュ > 상추
Lettus

15.　ハングル > 한글
Korean language

18.　ノッポ（のっぽ）> 키가 큰 사람, 키다리
Guy with long leg

19.　パッチ > 바지>일본에서는 남자들이 착용하는 내복 바지와 같은 것을 말합니다.
underwear pants. Its like another layer before pants

24.　オモニ > 어머니 
Mom

25.　アジュンマ > 아줌마
Korean lady (married)

26.　サムキョプサル > 삼겹살
Korean BBQ Pork

27.　チョギヨ・ヨギヨ > 저기요/여기요 
Excuse me

28.　アンニョンハセヨ > 안녕하세요
Annyonghasayo!

29.　マシソヨ > 맛있어요  마시써요 라고 발음.
Its delicious

30.　カムサハムニダ > 감사합니다  일본식발음으론 캄사하므니다.ㅋ
Thanks

31. オッパ > 오빠 
    Oppa

32.　オイキムチ > 오이김치
Kimchi
오이소박이를 오이키무치 라고.  일본 오이김치에는 부추대신에 무가 들어가있죠^^

34.　トックポーキ > 떡볶이 토크포-키 라고 발음해요.
Dduk-bok-ki

35.　サランヘヨ > 사랑해요
I love you

37.　ケンチャナヨ > 괜챦아요  켄챠나요 라고 발음.
Its okay

38.　チャミスル > 참이슬 
Charm-i-sul  - Soju brand
챠미스르 라고 발음.  참이슬 좋아하는 분들 많아요. 심지어는 처음처럼 까정...

39.　キンパプ  > 김밥  킴파프 혹은 킴파브 라고 발음
Kim-bob - kimbob name of food

40.　サムゲタン > 삼계탕  사무게탕 이라고 발음. 한국가면 삼계탕코스는 필수～
chicken soup

I just add comments under original source also while I am reading there some words doesn't make sense or not being used are removed.

Answer (score -4):

http://www.korean.go.kr/front/etcData/etcDataView.do?mn_id=46&etc_seq=91

Yes. National Institute of Korean Language (www.korean.go.kr) published the book terms from Japanese in 2005. You can download *.hwp file in above link.

Comment: The question is about Japanese words that came from Korean, not the vice versa.